# Hello new to ansible and a little stuck on copying with loops

Tags: ansible

I have this

```yaml
- name: cp images
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src }} "
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: u=rw, g=rw, o=r
      loop:
        - { src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioa.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioa.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtiob.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtiob.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioc.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioc.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvfp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VFP/virtioa.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Juniper/VSRX/junos-vsrx3-x86-64-20.4R1.12.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vsrxng-20.4R1.12/virtioa.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxpfe-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow}
        - { src: images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1.10-re-qemu.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxre-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Cisco/L2/vios_l2-adventerprisek9-m.SSA.high_iron_20180619.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/viosl2-adventerprisek9-m.03.2017/virtioa.qcow2}
        - { src: images/Cisco/L3/vios-adventerprisek9-m.vmdk.SPA.157-3.M3, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T.vmdk}
```

I'm trying to use Ansible to auto set up EVE-NG
I'm getting this error below

```
\n\t/home/ablake/Documents/Documents/personal-git/ansible/main/images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtiob.qcow2 
on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

Now I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong, I see in the error log its got \n\t in front of the dir I have no idea where this is coming from, is this the problem? I don't know if it is or its just ansible debug

now without the loop below

```yaml
    - name: copy PFE to EVE-NG
      tags: QFX
      copy:
        src: images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow
        dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxpfe-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow
```

that works I maybe missing something super basic with loops but I don't understand the difference and I'm a little stuck sorry

Also tried with quotes below

```yaml
- name: cp images
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src }} "
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      loop:
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioa.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioa.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtiob.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtiob.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioc.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioc.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvfp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VFP/virtioa.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/VSRX/junos-vsrx3-x86-64-20.4R1.12.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vsrxng-20.4R1.12/virtioa.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxpfe-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow'}
        - { src: 'images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1.10-re-qemu.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxre-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Cisco/L2/vios_l2-adventerprisek9-m.SSA.high_iron_20180619.qcow2', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/viosl2-adventerprisek9-m.03.2017/virtioa.qcow2'}
        - { src: 'images/Cisco/L3/vios-adventerprisek9-m.vmdk.SPA.157-3.M3', dest: '/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T.vmdk'}
```

same error below

> "Could not find or access 'images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img '\nSearched in:\n\t/home/ablake/Documents/Documents/personal-git/ansible/main/files/images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img \n\t/home/ablake/Documents/Documents/personal-git/ansible/main/images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img \n\t/home/ablake/Documents/Documents/personal-git/ansible/main/files/images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img \n\t/home/ablake/Documents/Documents/personal-git/ansible/main/images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img  on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html shows that the hash values are quoted, while yours are not.

Comment: oh sorry mate I have tested it like that

but it was the same output
I was following this 

https://linuxhint.com/copy-multiple-files-ansible/
and it didn't have the quotes I then googled 

and found this with quotes 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138936/ansible-could-not-find-or-access

Sorry tried that both failed same error

Comment: You have an extra space after your var expansion for `src`

Comment: OMFG im fucken dumb thank you so much  
Zeitounator I'm not going to say how long I was stuck on this for
god dam it, thank you so much. just going to go into hiding now omg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> *"Could not find or access 'images/... Searched in: ... main/files/images/ ... main/images/ ..."*.

The attribute [*src*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-src) of the module *copy* says:

> Local path to a file to copy to the remote server. This can be absolute or relative.

See [Search paths in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible) and the section [Resolving local relative paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#resolving-local-relative-paths) in particular. In your case:

> When you specify a relative path for a local file, Ansible will try to find that file ... relative to the file in which the task is defined ... Specifically, Ansible tries to find the file ... in its appropriate subdirectory—“files”, ...

This explains why Ansible searched for the files in the directories

- main/images/
- main/files/images/

It's up to you to provide the correct path. For example, given the tree at the controller

```
shell> tree images/
images/
├── Cisco
│   ├── L2
│   │   └── vios_l2-adventerprisek9-m.SSA.high_iron_20180619.qcow2
│   └── L3
│       └── vios-adventerprisek9-m.vmdk.SPA.157-3.M3
└── Juniper
    ├── QFX
    │   ├── vqfx-20.2R1.10-re-qemu.qcow2
    │   └── vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow
    ├── VMX
    │   └── vmx.18.2
    │       └── images
    │           ├── vFPC-20180605.img
    │           ├── virtioa.qcow2
    │           ├── virtiob.qcow2
    │           └── virtioc.qcow2
    └── VSRX
        └── junos-vsrx3-x86-64-20.4R1.12.qcow2
```

and the tree at the remote host

```
shell> ssh admin@test_11 find /opt
/opt
/opt/unetlab
/opt/unetlab/addons
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/viosl2-adventerprisek9-m.03.2017
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxpfe-10K-F-20.2R1.10
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vsrxng-20.4R1.12
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvfp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VFP
/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxre-10K-F-20.2R1.10
```

The playbook

```yaml
- name: Copy files to remote
  hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - name: cp images
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.src }}"
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [Copy files to remote] ******************************************************************

TASK [cp images] *****************************************************************************
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioa.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtiob.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioc.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/VSRX/junos-vsrx3-x86-64-20.4R1.12.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1.10-re-qemu.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Cisco/L2/vios_l2-adventerprisek9-m.SSA.high_iron_20180619.qcow2)
changed: [test_11] => (item=images/Cisco/L3/vios-adventerprisek9-m.vmdk.SPA.157-3.M3)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

How to debug

- Find files at the controller

```yaml
- name: Stat and assert files at the controller
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_src: "{{ dict(st.results|json_query('[].[item.src, stat.exists]')) }}"
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ item.src }}"
      register: st
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_src
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
    - assert:
        that: my_src_missing|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Error: Missing files: {{ my_src_missing }}"
      vars:
        my_src_missing: "{{ my_src|dict2items|
                                   rejectattr('value')|
                                   map(attribute='key')|
                                   list }}"
```

- Create or delete directories and files for testing

```yaml
- name: Create or delete directories and files
  hosts: test_11
  tasks:

    - name: Create local
      block:
        - name: Create local directories
          file:
            state: directory
            path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ my_files|map(attribute='src')|map('dirname')|unique }}"
        - name: Create local files
          file:
            state: touch
            path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ item.src }}"
          loop: "{{ my_files }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: create_local|d(false)|bool

    - name: Create directories at remote host
      file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files|map(attribute='dest')|map('dirname')|unique }}"
      when: create_remote|d(false)|bool

    - name: Delete local tree
      file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files|map(attribute='src')|map('dirname')|unique }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: delete_local|d(false)|bool

    - name: Delete remote tree
      file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files|map(attribute='dest')|map('dirname')|unique }}"
      when: delete_remote|d(false)|bool
```

- List of files

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/my_files.yml 
my_files:
  - {src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioa.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioa.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtiob.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtiob.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/virtioc.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvcp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VCP/virtioc.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Juniper/VMX/vmx.18.2/images/vFPC-20180605.img, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vmxvfp-18.2R1.8-domestic-VFP/virtioa.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Juniper/VSRX/junos-vsrx3-x86-64-20.4R1.12.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vsrxng-20.4R1.12/virtioa.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1-2019010209-pfe-qemu.qcow, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxpfe-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow}
  - {src: images/Juniper/QFX/vqfx-20.2R1.10-re-qemu.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vqfxre-10K-F-20.2R1.10/hda.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Cisco/L2/vios_l2-adventerprisek9-m.SSA.high_iron_20180619.qcow2, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/viosl2-adventerprisek9-m.03.2017/virtioa.qcow2}
  - {src: images/Cisco/L3/vios-adventerprisek9-m.vmdk.SPA.157-3.M3, dest: /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T/vios-adventerprisek9-m.SPA.156-1.T.vmdk}
```

Comment: thank you so much mate, just going to add all this to my notes on ansible thank you